# Can someone explain how below code generates Id for zombies in Solidity?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

```
struct Zombie {
   string name;
   uint dna;
   uint32 level;
   uint32 readyTime;
   uint16 winCount;
   uint16 lossCount;
 }

Zombie[] public zombies;
function _createZombie(string memory _name, uint _dna) internal {
    uint id = zombies.push(Zombie(_name, _dna, 1, uint32(now + cooldownTime), 0, 0)) - 1;
}
```

Please explain how the above line code **uint id** generates an id for zombies in the _createZombie function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `zombies.push()` happens, it returns the new length of array `zombies`
so, it gets saved in the `id` as `zombies.length - 1` which gives you current index of the Zombie data stored.

Note: I guess this code snippet will not run on latest versions of solidity compiler, as there would be some warnings.